# Remove all last commas between brackets

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to format the following as JSON (in Python):

```
{
   "sessionTimeout":"3600.0",
   "serverVersion":"LK_LK-NL-7_188-176-419",
   "worldDawn":"2018-10-09 06:00:00 Etc/GMT",
   "Data":{
      "Player":[
         {
            "nick":"Player11226400",
            "points":"44",
            "alliancePermission":"0",
            "isOnVacation":"false",
            "id":"5048",
            "rank":"561",
            "entityName":"Player",
         },
         {
            "nick":"Player11230580",
            "points":"15",
            "alliancePermission":"0",
            "isOnVacation":"false",
            "id":"5215",
            "rank":"2081",
            "entityName":"Player",
         },
         {
            "nick":"Player11291581",
            "points":"15",
            "alliancePermission":"0",
            "isOnVacation":"false",
            "id":"5942",
            "rank":"2081",
            "entityName":"Player",
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Every JSON validator of course tells me that this is not valid JSON because of the trailing "," before each }, so I want to remove that comma. I tried removing them with .replace('"Player",", '"Player"') but I don't consider this as a good solution. This because I also have trailing "," in for example a Alliance or Habitat string ("Habitat", & "Alliance",)

Could anyone help me with finding a better solution to this problem?

Comment: is this in a text file, or in python code??

Comment: @blue_note This is a string in Python, an endpoint response.

Comment: A hacky solution could be `.replace(",\n}", "\n}")`. Although the best solution would be to generate the JSON correctly if possible.

Comment: @CarlosGonzalez That does not seems to work

Comment: With SublimeText editor I used this regex to find all of the problematic "," characters: `\",\n .*\}`. You can also use this regex in your python code (but I didn't try, so I do not post the code).

Comment: The proper solution is obviously to fix the "endpoint" that returns this so it returns json instead of the internal string representation of a Python dict.

Comment: Doesn't a regex like: `re.sub(r',(\s*[]}])', '\1', text)` work? You simply want to remove all commas that are right before a `}` or `]`. Obviously this breaks if you have strings that also contain in their text these commas so a 100% correct solution cannot be achieved with a simple regex....

Comment: I refrain to downvote and vote to close this question because of its upvotes and answers. Is there something I'm missing here? There is no attempt at all, not a description of the issue OP had while trying to solve the problem by himself. Just his requirements (thankfully with at least an example of the input) with the hope that someone else will think and possibly write the code for him. While I agree that this might be useful in future to someone else...how can it be a good question at all???

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti You shouldn't change your pattern of voting/voting to close just because a question/answer is upvoted.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta it's true but if 7 people voted up and 1 voted down...then there is a chance I'm pretty wrong about it, that's why I'm _asking_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two solutions:

First one, cool if your json file doesn't have `null` or `false/true` booleans would be to read the input using `ast.literal_eval` which can process those commas, then dump back the dict as json if needed:

```
d = ast.literal_eval(txt)
print(json.dumps(d,indent=4))
```

if you can't, you can use a regex to remove commas that happen before a newline if the next line starts with spaces + closing braces/brackets:

```
import re

print(json.loads(re.sub(",(\n\s+[\}\]])",r"\1",txt)))
```

here's a full snippet containing the 2 approaches with a cut-down version of your input:

```
import ast,json

txt = """{
   "sessionTimeout":"3600.0",
   "serverVersion":"LK_LK-NL-7_188-176-419",
   "worldDawn":"2018-10-09 06:00:00 Etc/GMT",
   "Data":{
      "Player":[
         {
            "nick":"Player11226400",
            "rank":"561",
            "entityName":"Player",
         },
         {
            "nick":"Player11230580",
            "rank":"2081",
            "entityName":"Player",
         },
         {
            "nick":"Player11291581",
            "rank":"2081",
            "entityName":"Player",
         }
      ]
   }
}"""

print("ast literal eval:")
d = ast.literal_eval(txt)
print(json.dumps(d,indent=4))

import re

print("regex:")
d = json.loads(re.sub(",(\n\s+[\}\]])",r"\1",txt))
print(json.dumps(d,indent=4))
```

both methods successfully parse your input file. The first method will work flawlessly as long as there are no null pointers & booleans, the second method may fail in some obscure formatting cases. In case of bad luck, you can hack something in between.

Answer (score 6):

Since JSON is a subset of YAML, where dangling commas are permitted, you can use a yaml parser here.

```
pip install pyyaml
```

The library has a `load` function, similar to the standard library `json.loads`.

```
import json, yaml
json.dumps(yaml.load(jsondata))
```

You can also use `ast.literal_eval` for this particular data. But unlike `pyyaml` that doesn't work if your json contains literal `false`, `true` or `null` values.

Answer (score 0):

Use python's json module to export python dict to valid json:

```
import json
json.dumps(<your-dict>)
```

Comment: The OP does not have a dictionary, just a bad formatted text.